# How to create a scroll to top functionality inside a div in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, scroll

I have used this code this is only working for windows not inside a div tag.Please check the code in the comment.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wk6zsv  sample code,use this just to refer the code i used.

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrolling-goto-top

Comment: Provide a sample code!

Comment: This seems to be for the window what i amasking is for inside the window